# BottomNavigationView não funciona no primeiro clique

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

Estou com um problema no meu menu de avançar, ele não funciona quando clico na primeira vez, é necessário clicar duas vezes para executar a ação

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
@Override
public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuAvancar:
            if (camposObrigatoriosWS()) {

                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                ClienteDao clienteDao = new ClienteDao();
                clienteDao.buscarUltimoID(db);
                //Verifica se quer continuar cadasto de pacote ou somente cliente
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastrarClienteActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog_cadastro_cliente, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                iniciarComponentesDialog(dialogView);

                dialogBuilder.create().show();

                btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        inserirCliente("N");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CadastrarClienteActivity.this, EscolherPacoteActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        inserirCliente("S");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CadastrarClienteActivity.this, CaixaDeEntradaActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                toastUtil.exibirToastCurtoPrazo(CadastrarClienteActivity.this, "Campos obrigatorios não informado");
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é porque tu está usando o `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener`.
Como o nome já diz, **Reselect**, é apenas chamado quando o item já está selecionado e é novamente clicado.

Para o seu caso, use o `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.